# Invalid session token npm API

Tags: node.js, npm, authentication

I'm using this [api](https://github.com/IMRC21/ClassevivaAPI) to login to web.spaggiari.eu but when I try to do so it appears this error: "Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid session token".

Also this error appears below:

> ** at request.then.res (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\ClassevivaAPI\index.js:28:26)
>       at tryCatcher (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\Marian\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)**

This is where the error occours:

```
request(req)
    .then(res => {
        var result = {};
        var cookies = parseCookies(res.caseless.dict['set-cookie']);
        if (cookies.PHPSESSID) {
            result.sessionId = cookies.PHPSESSID;
        } else throw new Error('Invalid session token');
        if (res.body.data.auth.verified && res.body.data.auth.loggedIn) {
            return new Session(result.sessionId)
        } else throw new Error(res.body.error[0] || res.body.data.auth.errors[0] || 'Failed to authenticate')
    })
```

Note: I have changed the "uri" that is the link where it will do the request in the index.js file because the previous one thrown a 503 error.